Firebase returns no result in ios testflight using capacitor
Hi im using nextjs with capacitor and have firebase authentication. everything works fine on local configuration
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.xxx.app',
  appName: 'xxx',
  webDir: 'out',
  bundledWebRuntime: false,
  // No server configuration for production
};

export default config;

as soon I switch to production configuration

import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.xxx.app',
  appName: 'xxx',
  webDir: 'out',
  bundledWebRuntime: false,
  server: {
    androidScheme: 'https',
    iosScheme: 'capacitor'
  }
};

export default config;

in this configuration signInWithEmailAndPassword returns no result ( no success no fail )
this is the last network message im getting
URL: https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=XXXXX
Status: 200 OK
Source: Network
Address: 216.58.213.106:443

whats interesting tho is that if i enter wrong credentials resposne is returned.
can anybody help? tried everything already...
